# WPF and OxyPlot: Checkable ContextMenu, dynamically generated

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have a WPF window with an OxyPlot view. I'm trying to add a per-serie hide/show functionality, based on a dynamically generated, checkable context menu of the plot.
The idea is to have an `ObservableCollection<T>` object, bound to the `ItemsSource` of the context menu, where T is a class that contains basically the series title as string and the default check status as boolean.

**Excerpt of View.xaml:**

```
<oxy:PlotView
    x:Name="oxyPlot"
    Model="{Binding PlansPlotModel}"
    Controller="{Binding PlansPlotController}">

    <oxy:PlotView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding PlansPlotContextMenuItems}">
            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Title}"
                              IsCheckable="True"
                              IsChecked="{Binding IsCheckedByDefault}" />
                </DataTemplate> 
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        </ContextMenu>
    </oxy:PlotView.ContextMenu>
</oxy:PlotView>
```

The context menu is displayed correctly, but the checkboxes are in the wrong place, and it has a strange behaviour on mouse hover:

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected result]

**Actual result:**

[image: Actual result]

What am I missing?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Use ItemContainerStyle instead :

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding IsCheckedByDefault}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsCheckable" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```